# Defining a square in the complex plane using $A=z$ and $O=\text{origin}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm currently working with complex calculations and how it looks on the complex plane, and I have an exercise where I am ment to define the points $B$ and $C$ by using $A=z$ and $O= \text{origin}$ knowing that all the points make up a square $OABC$, defined in the counterclockwise direction.

Now, the solutions says that the point $C=iz$ and that point $B=z+iz$, which is as I understand the same as rotating by $90$ degrees whenever I multiply with $i$.

However, would it also be correct to say that $C=-\overline{z}$, and the point $B=z-\overline{z}$?

Comment: What's $origo$?

Comment: @5xum Oh, sorry, thought that was the correct translation, I mean origin. Fixing :)

Comment: Follow up: did you ever find out how to draw a square in the complex plane starting with a single arbitrary value of $z$?

Comment: Nope, not really, didn't wonder about that yet though. However, Isn't that something to do with orthogonality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $origo$ is the origin, then no, the points

$$O,z,z-\bar z, -\bar z$$

do **not** form a square. For example, if $z=1$, then all the points are on the real line, so obviously they cannot form a square, since they are $0,1,0,-1$.

---

In fact, the only time the points form a square is if the argument of $z$ or $\bar z$ is $\frac\pi4$, i.e. when $z=x\pm xi$ for some real $x$. The easiest way to see this is to simply sketch the four points - since $-\bar z$ is actually the point $z$, mirrored over the $y$ axis, you can easily see that the angle at $0$ (the angle $AOC$) is equal to $\pi-2\arg z$

Comment: Does it work out if $z$ is never only a real number?

Comment: @PhyCoMath It doesn't work for $z=1$, so how could it work for all real numbers?

Comment: What I mean, does it work whenever $z$ has an imaginary part?

Comment: @PhyCoMath No, it only works if the angle of $z$ is $45$ degrees (see my extended answer). For example, it works for $z=1+i$ and $z=1-i$ but it doesn't work if $z=1+xi$ for $x\neq 1,-1$.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you, I drew it in 45 degrees angle, so that probably why I saw it work :)

Comment: @PhyCoMath Probably, yeah. Never draw pictures that are too pretty, they may mess with you.

Answer (score 0):

A square in the complex plane can be constructed by a simple chain linkage as follows:

$$
O=0\\
A=z\\
B=A+ze^{i\pi/2}\\
C=B+ze^{i\pi}
$$

The result is a square for any arbitrary $z$. Of course, for plotting purposes you would create the vector $w=[O,A,B,C,O]$.